# SAX parser not taking multiple attributes for a tag

Tags: xml-parsing, sax

I want to parse the following XML file and print the list of all the attributes for the tag book. I am parsing with SAX parser. The problem is it is printing only the first attributes. The other attribute is not getting printed.
The XML is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101" action="lock">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
   </book>
 </catalog>
```

How should I write the code for printing all the attributes for the tag book.

Comment: just curious, why do you have a pig-like avatar? :)

Answer (score 0):

The SAX callback for startElement can look like this. Here the attributes are parsed in a loop:

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                         String qName, Attributes atts)
throws SAXException
{
    System.out.print("<"+qName);
    for(int i=0; i<atts.getLength(); i++) {
     System.out.print(" "+atts.getQName(i)+"=\""+atts.getValue(i)+"\"");
    }
    System.out.println(">");

}
```

Comment: for other languages than java it should work similar: iterate over 'atts'

Comment: Yes it should but it is not doing it properly.